# NSXMLParser "foundCharacters" delegate method not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, google-maps, nsxmlparser

I was having issues parsing XML, so I went through my code with NSLogs and noticed 
`- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string`
was not called.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<locations>
<location>
<name>Americas</name>
<address></address>
<gid>CoQBdAAAAE2tdzw4RGvnvaUZTk6N1ByNtosmD--ZYfcmkkPkR6R6v_nN9gJCO1INOVg-S5rzy7BATEUmvAQzh8hClafZbph2wSgfD28gXNJAttXLUbqzQMaql3rVbisSUv2a2r_H6ktOSaI5lLvf0GNthT5jn2JfAdD_HfUls6qhMvrm5e5XEhDcF5uRjlfpSqI_aciS_QPaGhQVVHenbOKZBQMSoCzsoIsdfw313Q</gid>
<type>
<1>political</1><2/><3/><4/><5/>
</type>
<phone></phone>
<rating></rating>
<icon>http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png</icon>
<website></website>
<longitude>-105.2551187</longitude>
<latitude>54.5259614</latitude>
</location>
</locations>
```

Relevant Part of my Implementation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
...
    if(!self.distance){self.distance = @"250000";}
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://fishbe.in/lab/reserverr/api/?term=%@&lat=%f&long=%f&limit=100&distance=%@", self.searchterm, location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude, self.distance];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [parser parse];
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    self.element = elementName;
    if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"locations"]) {
        self.items    = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(@"HI"); //Not outputted
    if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
        self.result = [[ReserverrSearchResult alloc] init];
        [self.result setTitle:string];
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
    } else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"address"]) {
        [self.result setVicinity:string];
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
    } else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"gid"]) {
        [self.result setGid:string];
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
    } else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"latitude"]) {
        [self.result setLatitude:[string floatValue]];
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
    } else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"longitude"]) {
        [self.result setLongitude:[string floatValue]];
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"location"]) {
        [self.items addObject:self.result];

    }

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    [self addAnnotations];

}
```

Edit - Added

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    NSLog(@"%@",parseError);
}
```

and got nothing.

Comment: Add `parser:parseErrorOccurred:` and see if / what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

1. As wain points out, you should implement `parser:parseErrorOccurred:` and it will tell you what's wrong.
2. I'd expect problems if the `searchterm` contains any characters that are reserved characters for a URL (e.g. a space, a plus sign, an ampersand, etc.). You should always percent-escape what I presume is a user provided search term and adding it to a URL:

   ```
   NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://fishbe.in/lab/reserverr/api/?term=%@&lat=%f&long=%f&limit=100&distance=%@", [self percentEscapeString:self.searchterm], location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude, self.distance];
   ```

   where you can use a method like the following:

   ```
   - (NSString *)percentEscapeString:(NSString *)string
   { 
       NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                    (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                                    (CFStringRef)@" ",
                                                                                    (CFStringRef)@":/?@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                                    kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
       return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
   }
   ```

   Note, do not rely upon `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` to do the percent-escaping. You really want to use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`, like above.
3. As an aside, your XML is not well-formed. I don't believe that `NSXMLParser` will accept element names that are numbers. So, instead of:

   ```
   <type>
       <1>political</1><2/><3/><4/><5/>
   </type>
   ```

   You might want:

   ```
   <types>
       <type>political</type>
       <type></type>
       <type></type>
       <type></type>
       <type></type>
   </types>
   ```

   Or, if you really need those numeric identifiers:

   ```
   <types>
       <type id="1">political</type>
       <type id="2"></type>
       <type id="3"></type>
       <type id="4"></type>
       <type id="5"></type>
   </types>
   ```

   In this latter example, your `didStartElement` can then use the `attributeDict` to extract the `id` identifier.
4. You report that `parseErrorOccurred` did not return anything. That means your server probably didn't return anything. And this could be caused by any of a number of problems. Try using your URL and return the data (for example, into a `NSString` or `NSData`, rather than the parser) and see what the response looked like. E.g., for testing purposes you could do:

   ```
   NSError  *error;
   NSData   *data    = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];
   NSString *results = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   // confirm error is `nil` and `results` is well-formed XML;
   // you can then pass the `data` to `NSXMLParser` with `initWithData` if you want
   ```

   I bet it's empty (which for certain search terms could be caused by a lack of percent-escaping, or from any of a myriad of server problems).
5. It might not be a problem, but it's worth noting that it's conceptually risky to save the results in `foundCharacters`, because sometimes between `didStartElement` and `didEndElement`, you'll have multiple calls to `foundCharacters` to retrieve the data. Generally people will instantiate a `NSMutableString` in `didStartElement`, append to it in `foundCharacters`, and then save it in `didEndElement`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked except now I'm getting the error: `2014-02-14 13:16:41.949 Reserverr[940:70b] Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=68 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 68.)" UserInfo=0x9d7d3a0 {NSXMLParserErrorLineNumber=2, NSXMLParserErrorColumn=323, NSXMLParserErrorMessage=StartTag: invalid element name
}`
after it parses the "gid" element.

Comment: @Phil Yep, that's my third point above, that numeric element names are not permitted. It's the `<1>` (etc.) that's not permitted. Hence my suggestion to change the XML accordingly.